# React Native:How to mock landscape mode with css without really changing the orientation?

Tags: react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { View,Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const window = Dimensions.get("window");
const screen = Dimensions.get("screen");
class FullScreenMediaPlayer  extends Component {
  
 
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={{
        width:screen.height,height:screen.width, transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}]}}>
        <WebView
        allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
        source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/vf0xwUbZqeo?rel=0&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&fullScreen=1'}}
/>
</View>
      );
    }
  }
  export default FullScreenMediaPlayer;
```

With this code my view doesn't stay in screen. I'm attaching the screenshot below
[image]

So how can I properly mock landscape orientaion with styles in react native?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useWindowDimensions`. As indicated in the documentation, the screen sizes change automatically whenever it change.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions